# Trying to store data from file to arrays of structure

Tags: c, arrays, structure

In the function below in my program, I am trying to read numbers from a text file and enter them to arrays of structure x,y,mass accordingly. The text file looks like this:

```
 1 2 3 //first number is x, second is y, and third is mass
 1 2 3
 1 2 3
```

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #define MAX 100
 struct cg { 
float x, y, mass;
 }masses[MAX];

int readin(void)
{
FILE *file = fopen("test.txt", "r");
int count;
if (file == NULL) {
    printf("Error: can't open files.\n");
    return 1;
}
else {
    while (1) {
         char c = fgetc(file);
         
        if (c != EOF) {
            if (count == 0) {
                masses[count].x = c;
            }
            else if (count == 1)
            {
                masses[count].y = c;
            }
            else if (count == 2)
            {
                masses[count].mass = c;
            }
            if (count != 3) {
                count++;
            }
            else { count = 0; }

        }
        else {
            break;
        }
        
    }
}
fclose(file);
}
```

I wrote this so far but i dont know if im going the correct way

Comment: Also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Answer (score 1):

If you are just getting started, get started correctly. When you approach a problem that requires reading *lines of data*, use a *line oriented* input function to read the data (e.g. `fgets` or POSIX `getline`). This allows you to *validate the read* separate and apart from parsing values from the line.

After reading and validating a line of data, you can then parse that data into whatever values you need. There are a great many tools available. `sscanf`, `strtod`, `strtok` or simply walking a pointer over each character in your line buffer comparing character-by-character as you go and taking the needed action.

Here, `sscanf` provides a very convenient way to parse 3 floating-point values from a line of text. (and use `double` instead of `float` for any engineering related work and always use integer values for currency). If you did not know how many values you were reading from each line, then walking `strtod` through the buffer would work fine.

Validate, validate, validate. If you read it -- validate what your read. If you convert it -- validate your conversion took place (and if needed that the value is within the expected range).

Putting those pieces together, you can do something similar to the following to read 3-values from each line into an array of struct (up to `MAX` elements). The code expects the filename to read as the first argument (or it will read from `stdin` by default if no arguments are given):

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum { NMEMB = 3, MAX = 100, MAXC = 512 };

typedef struct {
    double x, y, mass;
} cg;

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int n = 0;                      /* masses index */
    char buf[MAXC] = "";            /* buffer for each line */
    cg masses[MAX] = {{ .x = 0 }};  /* array of cg initialized to 0 */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    while (n < MAX && fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {  /* read each line */
        cg tmp = { .x = 0 };                    /* temporary struct */
        /* you should validate complete line read here */
        /* parse values into tmp and validate */
        if (sscanf (buf, "%lf %lf %lf", &tmp.x, &tmp.y, &tmp.mass) == 3)
            masses[n++] = tmp;      /* assign tmp to massess, increment n */
    }
    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close file if not stdin */

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf ("masses[%2d]  %5.2f %5.2f %5.2f\n", 
                i, masses[i].x, masses[i].y, masses[i].mass);

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** I have left validating that a whole line was read as an exercise. `strlen` and then checking that the last character read is `'\n'` will suffice)

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat ../dat/int3x20.txt
21 61 78
94 7 87
74 1 86
79 80 50
35 8 96
17 82 42
83 40 61
78 71 88
62 20 51
58 2 11
32 23 73
42 18 80
61 92 14
79 3 26
30 70 67
26 88 49
1 3 89
62 81 93
50 75 13
33 33 47
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/cg ../dat/int3x20.txt
masses[ 0]  21.00 61.00 78.00
masses[ 1]  94.00  7.00 87.00
masses[ 2]  74.00  1.00 86.00
masses[ 3]  79.00 80.00 50.00
masses[ 4]  35.00  8.00 96.00
masses[ 5]  17.00 82.00 42.00
masses[ 6]  83.00 40.00 61.00
masses[ 7]  78.00 71.00 88.00
masses[ 8]  62.00 20.00 51.00
masses[ 9]  58.00  2.00 11.00
masses[10]  32.00 23.00 73.00
masses[11]  42.00 18.00 80.00
masses[12]  61.00 92.00 14.00
masses[13]  79.00  3.00 26.00
masses[14]  30.00 70.00 67.00
masses[15]  26.00 88.00 49.00
masses[16]   1.00  3.00 89.00
masses[17]  62.00 81.00 93.00
masses[18]  50.00 75.00 13.00
masses[19]  33.00 33.00 47.00
```

Lastly, always compile with *warnings enabled*, and **do not** accept code until it *compiles cleanly without warning*. To enable warnings add `-Wall -Wextra` to your `gcc` compile string. (add `-pedantic` for several additional warnings). For VS (`cl.exe` on windoze), add `/Wall`. For `clang`, add `-Weverything`. Read and understand each warning. They will identify any problems, and the exact line on which they occur.